# Getting Initializing Gradle Language Server react native

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-code, gradle

I am new in react native programing .When i am trying to open react project in VS Code then in status bar it showing message `Initializing Gradle Language Server` and it continuously running all the day. Due to this i am not able to run the react native project. Please help.

Comment: is JAVA_HOME set?

Comment: Yes, JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME is already set